# How to stack two LinearLayouts?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm having an issue getting two linear layouts to stack (display block level). Instead, they're both side by side.

Any help is appreciated.

Here's my XML where the problem is. `Stack1` and `Stack2` are the ids for the two LinearLayouts in question. I shorthanded the other linear layout with `...` to save space.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_weight="0.8">

     <LinearLayout
     ...></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/Stack1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@id+/Stack2>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:background="#00010102"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:background="#00010102"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:background="#00010102"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:background="#00010102"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:background="#00010102"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: To start, for the outer LinearLayout, change to: `android:orientation="vertical"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LinearLayout which is a parent to both Stack1 and Stack2 is defined to be horizontal. Make it vertical to prevent it from getting set side by side.

Comment: Gosh dangit! Such a noob mistake. Thanks for your help!